# Intellij IDEA 2016.2 not responding to mouse clicks on OSX

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I cannot work any more with Intellij Idea, under OSX. After performing an IDE upgrade, the IDE main window (and any dialogs) has stopped responding to mouse clicks. The menu still works.

I have tried setting the log level to trace, with no success in getting any information of a possible exception when reacting to a mouse click.

The system is generating some thread dumps (a lot more under 2016.2, I have now downgraded to 2016.1.4). Is there a way to get more information to diagnose this issue?

Comment: Have you tried a reboot?  I've seen this under OS/X every once in a while and I've only fixed it with a reboot.  Even a full restart of IntelliJ doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Was the bug precipitated by an operating system or IDE upgrade?

Comment: @halfer the issue happened right after myh intellij idea upgrade.

Comment: @stdunbar hey! thanks a lot man! a system reboot fixed the issue. This is the first time I got this thing, though.

Comment: @stdunbar You could add an answer. It's worth having it in my opinion, for other people to find.

Comment: The same issue happened to me. It resolved itself once I tried showing it to my coworker (go figure).

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue. It turned out it was my mouse (Microsoft Sculpt wireless) that was causing the issue. After plugging it out and using the touchpad, it suddenly started working. The issue is not 100% reproducible, though. It sometimes works fine, sometimes doesn't

Upgrading OS X helped once, but then the problem came back. Updating IntelliJ and even reinstalling it with removing all data never helped.

@edit: I borrowed an identical Microsoft Sculpt Desktop set from my friend - it worked fine. I bought another one for myself, and so far it works (it's been 3 months now). Weird indeed.

Comment: I had the same issue with Intellij Idea and I am also using a Microsoft Sculpt Wireless mouse. Your answer did the trick: I reset the buttons of the Mouse to their original functions using the accompanying Microsoft Sculpt Software and Intellij started working again.

Comment: I didn't know that the buttons can be somehow programmed. I'm tempted to try it out, I still have the old keyboard and mouse :P thanks for sharing.

Comment: Had the same issue myself. Great tip for disconnecting and reconnecting.
No idea why this happens...

Comment: Huh. The problem still exists at the end of 2022. weird. And your suggestion worked. thank you